# How to build Autoware after modify source code?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using Autoware 1.13.0-melodic (docker)
I add some new source code in /home/autoware/Autoware/src/autoware/utilities/runtime_manager/scripts/runtime_manager_dialog.py file then build by command: `concol build`.
But when I run: `roslaunch runtime_manager runtime_manager.launch`, it has nothing change.

Can you help me how to build Autoware after modify source code?

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340684/how-to-build-autoware-after-modify-source-code?/) by [tiensu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45043/tiensu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-12-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@tiensu Where are you running `colcon build`? It must be at the base of the Autoware folder (e.g. `/home/autoware/Autoware`) in order for it to install to the correct location (`/home/autoware/Autoware/install`).

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-01-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blacksheep0303](https://answers.ros.org/users/60478/blacksheep0303/) on 2020-10-09**:
I'm sorry that this answer may not match your question.I saw your answer in another question about how to turn on the obstacle avoidance function of the  astar_avoid node.I want to say that I have exactly the same problem as yours,My vehicle cannot turn on the obstacle avoidance function. After encountering an obstacle, all it can do is stop. So,I'd like to ask you did you succeed in the end? If it succeeds,  can you share with me how it was achieved? I will be very grateful.Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@tiensu
Hi, I think you are running `colcon build` in another place.
I used `colcon build --packages-select (packages_name)` in

> /home/autoware/Autoware .

- `cd ~/Autoware`
- `colcon build --packages-select runtime_manager`

Then, It will be changed. :)

---

Originally posted by [cwhong](https://answers.ros.org/users/63044/cwhong/) with karma: 58 on 2020-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1